# Dataframe full of <NA>

Tags: r

I have two `data.frame`:  df1

```
structure(list(trial = c("SA1", "SA1", "SA1", "SA1", "SA1", "SA1"), CID =c(2565L, 8640L, 8456L, 8631L, 9329L, 8683L), SID = c(3L, 87L, 11L, 17L, 6L, 16L), GID = c("GID16170", "GID449286", "GID62427", "GID345692", "GID41372", "GID451760"),TID = c(5428L, 5428L, 5428L, 5428L, 5428L, 5428L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and df2

```
structure(list(GID = c("GID7173723", "GID4878677", "GID88208", "GID346403","GID268825", "GID7399578", "GID6624429"), `1A-1145442` = c(2L, 0L,2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L), `1A-1158042` = c(2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L), `1A-1158055` = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), `1A-1229616` = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), `1A-1236254` = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), `1A-1238114` = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

when I make the following `df2[df1$GID]` I get :

```
structure(list(GID = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `1A-1145442` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `1A-1158042` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `1A-1158055` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `1A-1229616` =c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `1A-1236254` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `1A-1238114` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c("NA", "NA.1", "NA.2", "NA.3", "NA.4", "NA.5", "NA.6"), class = "data.frame")
```

What is wrong with my code ? I want to expand the rows in df2 to 2700 rows. Basically df1 has 2700 rows and df2 2180 rows. Also df2$GID is basically `unique(df1$GID)` so all values of df2$GID are inside df1$GID. plus df2$GID has duplicated values.

Regards

Comment: Please show expected output based on `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: I expect something like df2 incremented by by the duplicated values of df1$GID

Comment: sorry I use this : df2[df1$GID,] instead of df2[df1$GID]

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this question.

Comment: I figured out my error, my columns were transformed from characters into factor at some stage of my pipeline and the subsetting just did not work converting everything into NA . sorry guys for the stupid question.